# How to get Android 2 project types available in Eclipse?

Tags: android

I just upgraded to the `Android 2 SDK`. (I was at `v1.5`)  .

I believe I followed all the instructions correctly, I installed the new SDK and then went into `Eclipse` and ran a software update from `dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`.

But when I then went to create a new project (after restarting Eclipse) all I had to choose from were `1.5 Android projects`.

To be honest, the steps for upgrading the `SDK` could be a little easier so it's entirely possible I missed something.

I'm glad Google has an auto-update feature starting with `Android 1.6` but unfortunately I'm out of luck since I'm on 1.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go `Window->Preferences->Android`, and make sure that SDK location is pointing to your new SDK location.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "all I had to choose from were 1.5 Android projects" I'm not quite sure what you mean, since there is a single Android Project Type in Eclipse (well, two if you could the Android Test Project).  I assume you mean that when you create an Android Project the only "Build Targets" available to you are 1.5 platforms.

[image]

Have you updated the Android Developer Tools (ADT) Plug-in for Eclipse as well as updating the SDK?  From what you said, it does sound like you have.

If you haven't, there are [instructions on how to do these at the Android Developers Website.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating)  A brief summary of these: select **Check for Updates** or **Software Updates** from the Help menu and then choose to update the ADT Plug-in when prompted.

In that dialog you can also check the version number of your installed version.  At the time of writing the latest version is `0.9.5`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for everyone's help.  To be clear (which I wasn't earlier), you're correct-- it's the build targets I was referring to when I said that I only saw Android 1.5 projects.

I did install the ADT plugin and will take all your tips and suggestions from here.  I'll let you guys know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the previous SDK completely and start again from scratch to make sure you aren't still using the old one. As you said, from v1.6 the SDK includes updating capabilities which make the process much easier, but the upgrade from v1.5 is prone to error.

The v2 SDK includes previous versions of the SDK for compatibility checking so you won't lose anything.